# VBA, ClearContents in columns only where range = string

Tags: vba, excel

I want to clear contents in a specified column(s) where `col A = "stack"`. I don't want to use `range("A2:A1000")` as this can change.

having some trouble here, not sure if I need to loop through each row, can anyone help me start this off.

```
Sub Clear()

Dim stack As Range
stack= Sheets("database").Range("A2").Offset("stack", 0).endxlup.Select
Range("CJ:CW").stack.ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean where "col A = 'stack'"?  Do you mean where "stack" first appears in Column A?  It's unclear what you want the range `stack` to be/do

Comment: I mean only clearcontents when Col A is Stack, if its overflow or anything else, do not clear contents for those rows.

Comment: Column A quite simply cannot be "stack" (what would that mean, every cell has "stack" in it? The only cell in column A is "stack"?...).  Do you mean a cell *in* column A?

Comment: Offset("stack", 0) ?

Comment: Are you saying all rows in column A that have "stack" in you want corresponding cells in same rows in CJ:CW cleared?

Comment: @BruceWayne I'd be surprised if you can.

Comment: @QHarr - Ah, I misread your comment. I thought you were suggestion a way to do that, not questioning it :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to take a punt on what you have described rather than the code.

> I want to clear contents in a specified column(s) where col A =
>   "stack". I don't want to use range("A2:A1000") as this can change.

I will take that as being dynamically determine the end row in column A and then loop from `A2` to it. If column A value, for a given cell, is "stack" then clear the contents of `CJ:CW` in the same row.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ClearCells()
    Dim mainRange As Range, rng As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("database")
        Set mainRange = .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        For Each rng In mainRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            If rng.Value = "stack" Then
                rng.Offset(, 87).Resize(1, 14).ClearContents
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

Array version:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ClearCells()
    Dim mainRange As Range, arr(), i As Long, j As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("database")
        Set mainRange = .Range("A2:CW" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        arr = mainRange.Value
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            If arr(i, 1) = "stack" Then
                 For j = 1 To 14
                     arr(i, 87 + j) = vbNullString
                 Next
            End If
        Next
        mainRange = arr
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you describe the `resize` part? What is 1,14?

Comment: @excelguy see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize)

Comment: why resize range?

Comment: do you not wish to clear CJ:CW? That is 14 columns wide.

Comment: @QHarr Yes, I am sorry. Anyway to speed this up? I have to go through 6k rows and clear them for these 14 cols?

Comment: Yes. 1) Use arrays or 2) Use autofilter. I will update with an arrays version for you.

Comment: Array version added

Comment: thank you @QHarr . Any chance you could explain vbnullstring?